# Updating app using REST API calls

Tags: android, ios

My question is really more of needing some ideas on how to solve this problem.  I have a shopping app built in iOS and Android.  Once an item is added to the cart, there is a cart view (TableViewController in iOS and Recycler View in Android) where the user can change the quantity of each item in the cart with a minus or plus button.  Each time one of the buttons is tapped it calls a REST API to our server to change the quantity on the server and the API responds with the new quantity, that I use to update the screen with.

The PROBLEM:
We have a requirement that if the quantity is 1 and the user taps the minus button, we pop up a message that says: Are you sure? Changing the quantity to 0 will delete the item from the cart.

The issue is that if the quantity is anything greater than 1 and the user taps the button fast enough, they can actually get the quantity to go down to 0 or even -1 before the API calls catch up to update the screen fast enough, so that they effectively can by pass the message.

I've Tried:
Checking the quantity each time the API responds which does tell me when the quantity is zero, but it is too late, the quantity has already been set to zero on the server at that point.

We currently have the API calls set up so that they are queued up so that if the user wants to tap the button a couple of time they can just do that and go on, and the app will catch up once the API responses come back.

Any ideas on how I can keep the user from tapping the minus button more than they should?

Thanks for any help or ideas you can give.

Comment: Ok first of all, thank you everyone who responded.  The ideas given definitely helped my group get to our final solution.  So after explaining all the ideas below, each of them had some (real or perceived) drawback that someone would bring up, so finally I suggested that we just remove the requirement to pop up the message and let the user be in charge.  We ended up doing that plus showing a popup letting the user know what item number just got deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the application requirements you could try to block the user to click on the minus/plus buttons. It could be done by enabling/disabling them or showing a 'loading message' while you communicate with the API.

If you can change the requirements, a 'remove' button could be added to replace the '0 quantity' verification. This way you'd add a verification to your UI component to not allow values < 0.

Another solution would be not to perform any API calls until the user decide the quantity, using a 'next step' button, for example (to lead the user to the next step of the shopping process).

Comment: Going to run these ideas by the QA department to see if any of them will fly.  I really like "not to perform any API calls until the user decides the quantity".  This will make a drastic drop in the number of API calls, for example, if the quantity is 10 and they want just 4 they currently would tap the minus button 6 times and each of those is an API call to change the quantity by -1.  I'll let you know.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: We didn't end up going with any of these ideas directly, but once I shared these with the group, it led the discussion directly to the solution we finally came up with. See comment on the main question for anyone wanting more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable or hide that button when user press that button and enable/show that button when you will get api response. By this user will able to press button one at a time and the next trigger of the button will be done after the response of previous api called. Just make sure you have something like loader so that user will not stuck on that screen until user get the response.

Comment: I should have included this in the question, but I can't stop the user like that, the client likes the fact of how fast the user can change the quantity.  But your idea is a good one, if we could.  The app really works great most of the time, it is now down to these nit picky things in the edge cases where you do some thing weird like have a quantity of 3 and then tap the minus button 4 times really fast.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a label on screen telling the user the current amount of an item.

So you could just in the code of your app access this label's value and check if it is going to be 0 once your minus button gets pressed and then take actions (e.g. disable the button, show an alert or simply don't alter the amount in the background)

This way you can, on the one hand, inform the user that the item is about to get deleted from the cart and, on the other hand, only make calls to your API with valid values.

Comment: Interesting...I need to think that one through...  Will let you know.